# I'm developing an Angular6 app, i am trying to send message from web using Strophe

Tags: typescript, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, strophe.js

This is method of my chat service,

```
sendCustomMessage(to, from, body) {
    const query = $msg({to: to, from: from, type: 'chat'}).c("body").t(body);
    console.log("query", query)
    this._xmppConnection.send(query);
   }
```

i am getting issue for **"$msg"**. the issue is "Cannot find name '$msg'.ts(2304)" ... please help me how to fix

Comment: sendCustomMessage(to, from, body) {
        const query = $msg({to: to, from: from, type: 'chat'}).c("body").t(body);
        console.log("query", query)
        this._xmppConnection.send(query);
       
     }

Answer (score 0):

Please do like this . issue is with the scope of variable .
import { Strophe, $pres, $msg, $iq } from 'strophe.js';